# Laplace Transformation for measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

The Laplace transform of real measurable functions on $[0,\infty)$ is defined by 
$L[f] = \int_{0}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt $

If $f \in L^{1}[[0, \infty)]$ prove that $L[f]$ exists and is bounded for all $s\geq 0$ . If $f_n ,f \in L^{1}[[0, \infty)]$ for all $n$, and $f_n\to f$ in $ L^{1}[[0, \infty)]$ norm, show that $ L[f_n]\to L[f]$ uniformly on $[0, \infty)$

I can't begin with the question. Tried for 3 days , but couldn't find anything to begin with. Can anybody suggest anything ?

What I have done so far... I don't know if it is correct or not

I have proved existence of $L[f]$ by showing as $f$ is measurable its integrable and hence $\int_{0}^\infty|f|dx \lt \infty$ and using $e^{-sx} \leq 1  \forall x \geq0, s \geq 0$  I have shown $|L[f]| \lt \infty $ which proves it exists I guess

Comment: Which statement you have difficulty with? Can you show that $L[f]$  exists? Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: I have updated the question with my progress so far

Answer (score 0):

You have already shown that $L[f]$ is bounded: it is bounded by $\int |f|$.

Now $|L[f_n](s)-L[f](s)| =|\int_0^{\infty} [f_n(t)-f(t)] e^{-st} dt| \leq \int |f_n(t)-f(t)| dt$ which shows that $L[f_n](s)\to L[f](s)$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you, it was easy. I checked your site statsmath, it has very nice questions